# custom container

Tags: alv, dynpro

In SAP, can we have a push button on custom container in ALV. Is it possible or is there any other possibilities for that?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would rather use custom containers for things like tableviews. If you are working with the standard Dynpros you can just add a button in the dynpro designer and implement the behaviour you would like. To give a more detailled answer, I would need to know what you are planning to do. Of course you can also create a ALV grid and modify the buttons which are displayed there. Maybe you elaborate a little bit more what you're planning to do and then I can give you a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible - check out class CL_GUI_TOOLBAR and the associated documentation (like http://help.sap.com/printdocu/core/Print46c/de/data/pdf/BCCITOOLBAR/BCCITOOLBAR.pdf) and sample programs. AFAIR there's a demo program that lets you assemble a toolbar dynamically, I just don't remember the name. You'll usually want to insert some kind of splitter first, then add the toolbar to one side of the container so that you can place other elements like trees or tables next to it.